# Java.nio.Files.move is throwing exception when moving files multiple times

Tags: java, file, nio, move

I have a scenario in which stress testing is opening, moving and closing a file in loop multiple times. Here is the sample snippet:

```
String path = "TestFile.txt";
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    System.out.println("opening file " + i + " times");
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
    File f = new File("temp.txt");
    if (f.exists())
        f.delete();

    boolean retValue = f.createNewFile();
    if (retValue) {
        file.close();
        Files.move(Paths.get("temp.txt"),Paths.get(path),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error reporting");
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code it is throwing exception after running 300~400 times.

> *Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\angupt\Desktop\temp.txt ->
>   C:\Users\kellogs\Desktop\TestFile.txt     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:81)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>     at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)    at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)    at
>   temp.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:37)*

I guess this exception is occurring because file is opening, moving and closing very fast, but I don't know how to properly handle this scenario. Thread.sleep also not working. Please help me out to find why this is happening and how can I get rid of this situation.

Comment: The documentation claims that exception can **only** be thrown if `REPLACE_EXISTING` is not specified.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-  File a bug with Oracle.

Comment: Works fine with "1.8.0_51".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know will it help but I had this problem when options for moving was set like that:

```
    CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
            ,StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
     };
     Files.move(source, target, options);
```

When I get rid of COPY_ATTRIBUTES it started to work as it should!

```
    CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
     }; 
     Files.move(source, target, options);
```